# How should I attach crown molding to cabinets with limited space?

Tags: cabinets, molding

I am putting up some crown molding on top of some existing cabinets, but I only have about 12 inches of clearance.  In the past when I have done projects like this, I have used a finishing nailer or brad nailer, however with this space, the tool won't fit.

What options or tool can I use to attach crown molding in this limited space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a nail spinner on the end of a drill.  It's a small tool that chucks into the drill.  Put a nail into the end of it and it spins it into wood.  A final tap with a nail set puts the nail below the surface.  It's a cabinetmakers tool and it prevents splitting the wood when driving finish nails into moldings (particularly oak).

http://www.craftsman.com/craftsman-nail-spinner/p-00902601000P

I wouldn't recommend using the palm nailer....  They're not easily controlled and you risk damaging the molding itself.

Comment: In this case, to get the crown molding on top of the cabinet, I used a 90 degree drill (only needed 4 inches of clearance) and screws to get it in.  I did this before I knew about the nail spinner and will add that to my list of things to try next time.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a good construction adhesive to glue it in the areas you cannot drive a nail through.  Make sure to use a scrap piece of molding to wedge the piece against the wall until the glue dries.

Comment: I was putting crown molding on the top of a cabinet and not attaching to the wall, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

A [palm nailer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000E7SYZC) might work for this.

[image: Palm Nailer Image]

Comment: I did try the palm nailer, but as someone mentioned, I ran into problems.  First I bought a cheap one which had its issues.  I then bought a Rigid that worked much better and I had some better control, but the wood was too hard for nailing.  I kept bending nails.

In the end a 90 degree drill and screws did the trick with pre drilled guide holes.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Rigid JobMax multi-tool with the [Auto-Hammer](http://www.ridgid.com/Tools/JobMax-Auto-Hammer-Head/EN/index.htm) head, which works in tight spaces. You'll have to set the nails below flush by hand though.